# Dropbox Bad OAuth request "Error 403"

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to integrate Dropbox in my IOS application.I created a new app by follwing the below procedure.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create

1 Selected Dropbox Api app.
2 Selected Files and Datastores.
Filled the fields regarding the app and clicked  "Create App".

After that in "App Details Screen" I selected browse datastores,I am getting the below error as shown in figure.

[image]

I had gone through this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs) and found that
[image]

But I am unable to fix the error.If any one solved this problem guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have uninstall and the reinstall..it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion here. You'll get that error if you try to browse datastores for an app that you haven't actually authorized yet. Once you go through the auth process in your app with this account (i.e. log in to the app), you'll be able to browse datastores. (Until you put something in there, there's nothing to look at on that page anyway.)

We should probably make sure that link is disabled until you've actually authorized the app.

Comment: No..not like that..If there are no tables/data existing it shows "no tables"..But it won't show error like this.

Comment: Yes, it will. I tried it myself to verify. I didn't say it had anything to do with whether there were tables or not. It has to do with whether there's a valid access token for your user with that app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same steps and that worked. There might be a problem with the Dropbox server. It happens sometimes. Here are the options I selected. It goes to the next page. Hope that helps![image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I followed the same procedure..But getting 403 error for past two days ..

Comment: Did you choose the same steps as I have in the screenshot? Try that once. It certainly works here. If still it does not work, dropping an email to the dropbox folks or contacting their forum might help.

Comment: Welcome :) Don't forget to up vote the answer if it helped you :)